# str.replace() replace char with "char"

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, str-replace

I have a script which processes data returned from a web API. The data returned is a string representation of a list of dictionaries.

I know about ast.literal_eval() to convert the string representation of the dictionaries into real ones.

The data looks like this (Reminder: those are strings, not dicts):

```
new = [{"id": "L0", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L1", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L2", "tags": null, "disable": false}]
```

Because 'null' and 'false' are not enclosed in quotes, ast.literal_eval() fails with an error.  If I manually add quotes to null and false above, it works perfectly.

I was trying to iterate through the strings and modify the substrings null and false to "null" and "false" with this, but it does nothing:

```
for i in new:
    i.replace("null", "\"null\"")
    i.replace("false", "\"false\"")
```

How do I modify those substrings to add enclosing quotes?  If possible I would prefer to modify the existing list (new[]) instead of creating a new one, but if I have to create a new one to get it to work, then that's what I will do.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `None` and `False`?

Comment: **@MarkS**, if **new** is a string then you a little correct with your approach. Do not use for loop. Just 2 lines are enough. Also do not forget to re assign the returned value after replace operation. Note that strings are immutable in Python. For example, `i = i.replace("null", "\"null\"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the data just before running `ast.literal_eval()`, possibly with `re` module:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval
from pprint import pprint

s = """new = [{"id": "L0", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L1", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L2", "tags": null, "disable": false}]"""

s = re.sub('null', '"null"', s)
s = re.sub('false', '"false"', s)
s = re.sub('new\s*=\s*', '', s)

new = literal_eval(s)
pprint(new)
```

Output:

```
[{'disable': 'false', 'id': 'L0', 'tags': 'null'},
 {'disable': 'false', 'id': 'L1', 'tags': 'null'},
 {'disable': 'false', 'id': 'L2', 'tags': 'null'}]
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit unclear. The list is a list, but the values of the list are strings that look like dicts.  That's why I stated I was trying for i in new:  I am iterating over each string in the actual list new.

Comment: @MarkS You need to provide then raw input and expected output in your question.

Comment: kesley, after adjusting my program a bit to accommodate the solution you provided, I got it to work they way I want.  I now successfully create a list of dicts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**@MarkS**, if **new** is a string representation of the list of dictionaries then you can also try the below code.

```
from ast import literal_eval

new = '''[{"id": "L0", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L1", "tags": null, "disable": false},
       {"id": "L2", "tags": null, "disable": false}]'''

new = new.replace('false', '\"false\"')
new = new.replace('null', '\"null\"')

print(new)
"""
    [{"id": "L0", "tags": "null", "disable": "false"},
       {"id": "L1", "tags": "null", "disable": "false"},
       {"id": "L2", "tags": "null", "disable": "false"}]
"""

print(literal_eval(new))
"""
    [{'id': 'L0', 'tags': 'null', 'disable': 'false'}, {'id': 'L1', 'tags': 'null', 'disable': 'false'}, {'id': 'L2', 'tags': 'null', 'disable': 'false'}]
"""
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit unclear. The list is a list, but the values of the list are strings that look like dicts.  That's why I stated I was trying for i in new:  I am iterating over each string in the actual list new.